# Injecting content script for Chrome extension isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've researched this topic a ton but something isn't clicking. I'm trying to make a simple Chrome extension. The details aren't important, but basically when the user clicks on a certain button on a certain website, the page is redirected to a different URL. I've put in dummy URLs just for illustration. Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Blah",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Blah blah",
    "icons": {  "16": "icon16.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "128": "icon128.png" },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["*://url1.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

contentscript.js (found this on another Stack Overflow question, not totally sure how it works)

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

script.js

```
document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", redirect);
function redirect() {
    console.log("Testing!");    // This works!
    window.location.replace("url2.org");
}
```

The text is logged to the console when I click the appropriate button, so I know I'm doing something right. However, I'm guessing I'm not actually injecting the script into the page, and that's why my page isn't redirecting. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your script wasn't injected, you wouldn't get the console log. So something else is a problem.

Comment: Also, there is no need to use the page-level injection here at all. You can simply put your `script.js` code in your `contentscript.js`. Page-level injection is only needed to bypass [context isolation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), which isn't needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

script.js

```
// wait that page finished loading
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
// for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
},false);
```

inject.js

```
// this is the code which will be injected into a given page...

document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener("click", redirect);
function redirect() {
   console.log("Testing!");    // This works!
   window.location.replace("url2.org");
}
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Inject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
       "js": ["script.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "http://example.com/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: However, I don't want the user to have to click on the extension icon for the code to be injected. I'd like the code to be injected automatically, so when the user clicks on the appropriate hyperlink, the page is redirected away to another URL.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for updating, but the code isn't working for me... Now I can't even get anything printed to the console.

Comment: Thanks again-- but I still can't get it to work. I'm still not even seeing the test message logged to the console.

Comment: Does the `inject.js` file is injected into the page?

Comment: How would I test if it was successfully injected?

Comment: @AlecvonBarnekow, can you elaborate on the inject piece of code, does it have to have a file structure going from root? E.g. if I have a folder and the popup is in another folder, am I navigating from root or from the popup? Thanks.